# Foreach code working - but asking for optimalization

Tags: php

The below code works and does output exactly what i want. I made a foreach loop getting the values of a specific field ($CustomFields...) which is part of a framework variable. Then is only counts that field when the condition is "group".
After that i want to het the average price of all fields / count.

```
// ########### Get average hourly rate for group classes
$itemsperhour = array();
$countperhour = 0;

foreach($listings as $listing) {
    if ($CustomFields->fieldValue('jr_typeoflesson',$listing,false,false) == 'group') {
        $itemsperhour[] = $CustomFields->field('jr_hourlyrateus',$listing,false,false);
        $countperhour = $countperhour + 1;
    }
}

//print_r($items);

if ($countperhour > 0) {
    $totalperhour = array_sum($itemsperhour);
    $averageperhour =($totalperhour / $countperhour);
    echo round($averageperhour,2);
} else {
    echo "No data";
}

unset ($averageperhour);
```

As said, the snippet works. But may I ask how other people would write such a script related to optimise such a piece of code (for speed and readability?
PHP 5.6+

Jasper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one way of optimizing:

```
$totalperhour = 0;
$countperhour = 0;
foreach($listings as $listing) {
    if ($CustomFields->fieldValue('jr_typeoflesson',$listing,false,false) == 'group') {
        $totalperhour += $CustomFields->field('jr_hourlyrateus',$listing,false,false);
        $countperhour = $countperhour + 1;
    }
}

if($countperhour > 0) {
    $averageperhour =($totalperhour / $countperhour);
    echo round($averageperhour,2);
    $averageperhour = '';
} else {
    echo "No data";
}
```

Comment: No by me, grateful for the answer. I am still checking your idea

Comment: Ok @Jasper. Every down-vote should have reason. SO is for sharing the knowledge, so everybody learns. Effort shouldn't be down-voted.

Comment: It's a Q&A site, and this is hardly an answer. It's a code-dump without any explanation as to what you changed and why you changed/improved what you changed. Effort should indeed be rewarded, but this doesn't show much effort.

Comment: Thanks @Qirel. Lets wait to hear from Jasper. As I have mentioned, its one-way of optimizing, of-course there are many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose to use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function for getting the average:

```
$averageperhour = array_reduce($listings, function($average, $listing) use (&$CustomFields)
{
    static $sum = 0;
    static $counter = 0;

    if ($CustomFields->fieldValue('jr_typeoflesson', $listing, false, false) == 'group') {
        $sum += $CustomFields->field('jr_hourlyrateus', $listing, false, false);
        $counter ++;
        $average = round(($sum / $counter), 2);
    }

    return $average;
}, 'No data');

echo $averageperhour;
```

Not sure about speed improvement (needs testing), but this variant seems to me like more readable.

Comment: It's not clear whether `$listing` is an `array` or just iterable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$itemsPerHour = [];

foreach($listings as $listing) {
    if ($CustomFields->fieldValue('jr_typeoflesson', $listing, false, false) !== 'group') {
        continue;
    }

    $itemsPerHour[] = $CustomFields->field('jr_hourlyrateus', $listing, false, false);
}

$countPerHour = count($itemsPerHour);

if ($countPerHour > 0) {
    $averagePerHour = array_sum($itemsPerHour) / $countPerHour;

    echo round($averagePerHour,2);
} else {
    echo "No data";
}
```